# javascript function is not executed

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Why alert("Test1") is executed, while alert("Test2") is not executed?
P.S. Currently I'm not using json `data`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var param = 10;
           $.getJSON(
                       'modules/mod_scheduler/updateList.php?param'+param,
                       function(data)
                       {
                           alert("Test1");
                           find_optimal_schedule();
                       }
           );
    });
</script>

<script language="javascript">
function find_optimal_schedule() {
    alert("Test2");
    //...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the `find_optimal_schedule()` function. If there is a syntax error in the part you don't show it would stop the function from running and thus not alert "Test2".

Comment: @nnnnnn: Currently this function is empty. It contains only alert("Test2"); which is not displayed.

Comment: Oh, OK - I guess I assumed (incorrectly) that `//...` represented more code. But if that's the whole function and the whole of that script block I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you post the whole page, including everything?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about it, but try changing this bit:

```
<script language="javascript">
```

into:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

And see if it runs.

Comment: I changed this line, but it did not help solve the problem. Maybe it does not see the function find_optimal_schedule()??

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug on Firefox and see what error appears in the Console?

Comment: Even the following does not work: $(document).ready(function() {
               alert("Test1");
               find_optimal_schedule();
               alert("Test3");
 }); I can see only "Test1"

Comment: There's likely a syntax error in `find_optimal_schedule()`, in the part of the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @nnnnnn: the content is just the following: function find_optimal_schedule() {
    alert("Test2");
}

Comment: The `type` attribute does nothing practical in HTML .. it is actually *not* in HTML5.

Comment: -1 The error has nothing at all to do with the deprecated language attribute. If it did, the code wouldn't run at all.

Comment: What happens when you run `find_optimal_schedule()` directly in the Firebug console?